# Is there retrograde analysis puzzle like "Point on the incorrectly drawn chess piece"?

Tags: problems, retrograde-analysis

Does anybody know a nice chess puzzle, where question states: "Exactly one piece is drawn incorrectly on this diagram, another piece must be drawn on it's position. Find incorrectly drawn piece."? One needs to make retrograde analysis of the given position and find, which from all pieces is drawn incorrectly.

I really would like to find such a puzzle.

---

P.S. I would rather like to *find* Old puzzle like this than to see you *creating* a new one, because:

1. I understand that it is easy to create a simple puzzle like [this](http://braingames.ru/chess/kw11pb22pb31pb33kb32rw21rw12.gif). But this would be too simple.
2. When you try to create it, it is easy to miss some combination. Meanwhile old puzzles are checked "by time".

But if you really would like to try to create a nice puzzle like this - you are welcome.

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. A diagram that, when one piece is replaced, becomes a chess puzzle? Your example is a legal position, so I'm not sure what it's intended to demonstrate (and my Russian isn't nearly good enough to go figure it out at the source site).

Comment: @HenryKeiter, 1. Yes, if I understood you correctly. 2. My diagram is illegal position if I am not mistaken, otherwise please show me any example of 2 last moves.

Comment: Example last two moves: starting position is `"8/8/8/8/8/1kp5/Rn3Q2/KR6 w - -"`: `1.Qxb2+ cxb2+`

Comment: @HenryKeiter, you are right. Thank you. THis is a reason why I don't try to create a more or less interesting puzzle by my own. I corrected the picture, hope not it is not legal position:)

Comment: You'll need something at `a3` as well, or else it's still just `1.Qxb2+ axb2+` from the starting position: `"8/8/8/8/8/pkp5/Rn4Q1/KR6 w - -"`.

Comment: Frolkin has done some rebuses like this, I've heard. Alas I don't know the details sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Raymond Smullyan's *Chess Mysteries of the Arabian Knights* has some problems where one of the pieces is actually a different piece; you have to figure out which piece.

The problems there which fit this description appear to be these:

3 5 23 28 29 30 39 41 42 43

Comment: Sorry, but what are these numbers?

Comment: The numbers of the problems. Smullyan numbered his problems in AK.

Comment: can you please describe (cite) at least one of them fully here?